# How to limit image size and extension other then jpg png or gif

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using below code to preview images before upload and it works fine. But how to fix Image extenstion such that user won't upload any invalid image and size also

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <title>Change image on select new image from file input</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>

<input type="file" name="file" id="profile-img">
<img src="" id="profile-img-tag" width="200px" />
<br />
<input type="file" name="file" id="profile-img2">
<img src="" id="profile-img2-tag" width="200px" />
<br />
<input type="file" name="file" id="profile-img3">
<img src="" id="profile-img3-tag" width="200px" />


  <script type="text/javascript">
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#' + $(input).attr('id') + '-tag').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("[type=file]").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code with multiple previews and inputs? I only see one.

Comment: @Noah can u check I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <title>Change image on select new image from file input</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>

</head>

<style type="text/css">
    .image-holder{
        height: 200px;
    }
    .image-holder img{
      max-height: 100%;
    }
</style>

<body>




<input id="fileUpload_one" type="file" multiple />
<div id="image-holder_one" class="image-holder"></div>



<script type="text/javascript">

$("#fileUpload_one").on('change', function () {

     //Get count of selected files
     var countFiles = $(this)[0].files.length;

     var imgPath = $(this)[0].value;
     var extn = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
     var image_holder = $("#image-holder_one");
     image_holder.empty();

     if (extn == "gif" || extn == "png" || extn == "jpg" || extn == "jpeg") {
         if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {

             //loop for each file selected for uploaded.
             for (var i = 0; i < countFiles; i++) {

                 var reader = new FileReader();
                 reader.onload = function (e) {
                     $("<img />", {
                         "src": e.target.result,
                             "class": "thumb-image"
                     }).appendTo(image_holder);
                 }

                 image_holder.show();
                 reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[i]);
             }

         } else {
             alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
         }
     } else {
         alert("Pls select only images");
     }
 });

</script>





</body>

</html>
```

Add class to the div where image are placing and accordingly give styling to image through css. Hope it helps i added the css and class to the div hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that your image tag and input tag both have different `id`s. If you give the image tag the same `id` as your `input` tag but give it the suffix of `-tag` then it will be its own unique `id`. Using this method you can use the following line:

```
$('#'+$(input).attr('id') +'-tag').attr('src', e.target.result);
```

To set the `src` attribute of the corresponding image tag.

See working example below:

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var extn = input.files[0].type.split('/')[1];
    var size = input.files[0].size;
    var maxSize = 40000; // file must be smaller than 40kb
    
    var valid = ["gif", "png", "jpg", "jpeg"];
    if (valid.includes(extn) && size < maxSize) {
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('#' + $(input).attr('id') + '-tag').attr('src', e.target.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }
}

$("[type=file]").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>

<input type="file" name="file" id="profile-img">
<img src="" id="profile-img-tag" width="200px" />
<br />
<input type="file" name="file" id="profile-img2">
<img src="" id="profile-img2-tag" width="200px" />
```

Comment: it works perfectly but how do I make sure they upload only valid image not other files....above my code works which I posted for same but How do I format your code to achive that?

Comment: your solution works perfect but how to add limit on file size and extension also?

Comment: @redface I'll modify my code, give me a few minutes

Comment: Ok I'm waiting..tried myself but no luck. Thanks for help

Comment: works perfectly but when I select any image with extension other then png there is no any preview?? can you help me?

Comment: @redface seems to work for me... make sure your image file size is smaller than 40kb (or adjust the `maxSize` value)

Answer (score 0):

Id's must be different on DOM and on your Javascript code.

```js
function readURL(input, inputId) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
        console.log(input)
            $('#' + inputId + '-tag').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
$(".profile-img").change(function(){
    readURL(this, this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="file" id="profile-img-1" class="profile-img">

<img src="" id="profile-img-1-tag" width="200px" />

<input type="file" name="file" id="profile-img-2" class="profile-img">

<img src="" id="profile-img-2-tag" width="200px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for multiple image upload and preview and also I added validations in it too.

JS code:

```js
function previewImages() {

  var preview = document.querySelector('#preview');
 
 
  
  if (this.files) {
    [].forEach.call(this.files, readAndPreview);
  }

  function readAndPreview(file) {

    
    
  // Make sure `file.name` matches our extensions criteria
    if (!(/\.(jpg|png)$/i.test(file.name)))  {
      return alert(file.name + " is as not image file");
    } 

   else if(file.size/(1024*1024) > 2 ) {
      return alert(file.name + " size is greater than 2MB");
    }
    
    var reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
      var image = new Image();
      image.height = 100;
      image.width = 100;
      image.title  = file.name;
      image.src    = this.result;
      preview.appendChild(image);
    }, false);
    
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    
  }

}
document.querySelector('#file-input').addEventListener("change", previewImages, false);
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
 <div class="multiple-img">
  <p class="choosetext">Choose multiple images :</p>
  <input id="file-input" type="file" id= "files" multiple>
          <div id="preview" ></div>
 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On File open /drop you get a file object 
//Drop senario

```
 c.ondrop = function (e) {
var file=e.dataTransfer.files[0];
       console.log(file.size);//Co,mpare here size
        console.log(this.files[0].type);////Co,mpare type here
            };
```

input type file senario

document.getElementById("inn").onchange = function (e) {

```
        var file =this.files[0];
       console.log(file.size);//Co,mpare here size
         console.log(this.files[0].type);////Co,mpare type here

        fread(this.files[0]);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the easiest. It's all your code. Just add desired `height` and `width` attributes while uploading image in your *JavaScript* code. Try This:

```js
$("#fileUpload_one").on('change', function () {
  //Get count of selected files
  var countFiles = $(this)[0].files.length;
  var imgPath = $(this)[0].value;
  var extn = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
  var image_holder = $("#image-holder_one");
  image_holder.empty();
  if (extn == "gif" || extn == "png" || extn == "jpg" || extn == "jpeg") {
    if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
      //loop for each file selected for uploaded.
      for (var i = 0; i < countFiles; i++) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
          $("<img />", {
            "src": e.target.result,
            "class": "thumb-image",
            "height": "200px",
            "width": "200px"
          }).appendTo(image_holder);
        }
        image_holder.show();
        reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[i]);
      }
    } else {
      alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
    }
  } else {
    alert("Pls select only images");
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="fileUpload_one" type="file" multiple />
<div id="image-holder_one"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```